# firmar un documento PDF teniendo un archivo PFX utilizando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, openssl

Yo implemente el siguente codigo para poder tomar un archivo PDF, un archivo pfx con una firma yasí poder firmar el PDF con esa firma.

```php
use phpseclib\File\X509;
use phpseclib\File\ASN1;

// Ruta del archivo PFX
$file_path = '/ruta/hacia/tu/archivo.pfx';
$password = 'contraseña_del_pfx'; // Contraseña del archivo PFX

// Ruta del documento PDF a firmar
$pdf_path = '/ruta/hacia/tu/documento.pdf';

// Cargar el archivo PFX
$pfx_content = file_get_contents($file_path);

// Extraer el certificado y la clave privada del PFX
$pfx = new X509();
if ($pfx->load($pfx_content)) {
    $private_key = $pfx->getPrivateKey($password);
    $cert = $pfx->getPublicKey();
}

// Firmar el PDF
$certificate = new X509();
$certificate->loadX509($cert);
$signature = $certificate->sign(file_get_contents($pdf_path), $private_key);

// Guardar el PDF firmado en una nueva ruta
$signed_pdf_path = '/ruta/hacia/tu/documento_firmado.pdf';
file_put_contents($signed_pdf_path, $signature);
```

Alguien puede ayudarme? el inconveniente lo encontré al querer utilizarlo, las librerias no funcionan

```
use phpseclib\File\X509;
use phpseclib\File\ASN1;
```

Gracias.!!

Comment: Cuando dices "las librerias no funcionan"... que es lo que no funciona? Hiciste algun tipo de debug para ir viendo que valores van tomando esas variables a medida que se ejecuta el codigo?

Comment: Entre a la librería que dices y el namespace es namespace phpseclib3\File deberías revisar el último actualizado

Comment: Cuando digo que no funcionan es que al llamar a la ruta que impacta en la función que las utiliza, el error que eroga es que no existen, habiendo seguido las instrucciones de instalación para Laravel al pie de la letra.
Si saben de alguien que las invoquen y les funcionen, les agradezco.

Comment: Goyo David Beaumont, si percibí que le agregaron el 3 en el llamado y probé y tampoco funciona. Gracias por la indicación.

Comment: Como instalaste el paquete? Cual version? "habiendo seguido las instrucciones de instalación para Laravel al pie de la letra" no ayuda mucho...  Por favor actualiza la pregunta con eso, el mensaje de error que te muestra (copiando y pegando, no solo dciendo "el error que eroga es que no existen") y lo que has intentado/investigado hasta ahora

Comment: Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta y sea mejor recibida. También, aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.